# Share System.Math functions with VBA Excel using a VB.NET DLL

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, dll

I am writing some geometrical math functions using VB.NET (VS 2015) to create a DLL (geoMath.DLL), including System.Math. I can build the DLL and use those functions in VBA Excel with no problem.

What I want to do is make the functions of System.Math also available for the VBA code, referencing only the geoMath.DLL.
I can use Math inside classes, like x=Math.Sign(y), but can´t see the Math functions in vba code.

Question: How can I share System.Math functions with vba using my custom DLL?

VB.NET code

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Math

Namespace Mat
    Partial Public Class geoMathmatica

    Public mathNET as System.Math

......
```

Answer (score 1):

Create methods in your DLL that mimic the System.Math functions.

```
Public Class MyDLL
    Public Shared Function Sin(AngleInRadians As Double) As Double
        Return System.Math.Sin(AngleInRadians)
    End Function
End Class
```

edit: Max using objects

```
Public Shared Function Max(val1 As Object, val2 As Object) As Object
    'tested with
    '  Dim ii As Integer = CInt(MyDLL.Max(7I, 2I))
    '  Dim dd As Double = CDbl(MyDLL.Max(7.3R, 2.42R))

    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf val1 Is Double
            Return System.Math.Max(DirectCast(val1, Double), DirectCast(val2, Double))
        Case TypeOf val1 Is Integer
            Return System.Math.Max(DirectCast(val1, Integer), DirectCast(val2, Integer))
            'etc - add others
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but how can I handle the functions that have overload, like Math.Max, that has 11 overloads? Set the arguments as "Object" and let Math.Max deal with types? Like: Public Shared Function myMax(val 1 as object, val2 as Object) as Object?

Comment: @LeoRon7 - I guess.  It can be made to work.  See edit above.